# Google Analytics 4 integration in react native

Tags: react-native, events, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a project based on react native and need to integrate with GA4

Is it true that i still need firebase analytics as the base code? Or is there direct integration without firebase analytics?

Any reference on where to start?

I need to integrate ga4 in react native. Is it possible without firebase sdk?

Comment: Firebase is from google Right ??

Comment: Yes it is from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS/Android apps, yes you would need to include the Firebase SDK to set up data collection. While for web, you'll need to add the Google tag to your web pages to begin seeing data in your Google Analytics 4 property.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-analytics-bridge
I was going through this npm package. Don't you think we can push events to google analytics by using this package without firebase?
I've google tag manager dashboard with container id and google analytics tracking id. Please let me know if this can be integrated without firebase sdk?